# Control the position of a list by rotating a DIV

Tags: jquery, rotation, mouse, drag

I have a long term goal and I'm slowly edging my way towards it, but I need a lot of help, don't really know what I'm doing yet?

Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/vjU5b/27/

My end goal is to have the red square control the position of the list, 
as in when the square rotates to the right (clockwise the list moves down to show a new line of text within the blue box area, then when the end of the list is reached the movement will be reversed, the square will rotate left (anticlockwise) and the list will slide up to show a line of text within the blue box, 
What I would really love to be able to learn is how to use a drag with the mouse around the red square to rotate the square and slide the list up and down and snap into position so the text is within the blue box.

At the moment I cannot get the list to continue moving as the square rotates, it just goes once, and from there on I have no idea how to get it to reverse or how to use a mouse drag to control it.

Any pointers/help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To get the list to continue moving you need this:

```
$('#list').animate({top : "+=20px"}, {duration:500})
```

instead of

```
 $('#list').animate({top : "=120px"}, {duration:500})
```

The second statement will only position it to top:120px, while the first one will decrement the position by 20px each time you click

in order to change direction you can do it this way [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eqGQ/)

Comment: Thanks, any idea of how to get it to reverse once it reaches a certain degree or height?

Comment: @user1681836 I added the solution in my answer

Comment: Thats amazing thank you, Now if you could tell me how to get the same action to happen with a mouse drag I will send you my house and my first born

Comment: that would require more work, i'll let you know asap (it's 4am here) :)

Answer (score 1):

you should change top of the list each time, like so:

```
var top = 120;

$(function(){
$('#box').click(function(){
    $('#list').animate({top : top + "px"}, {duration:500});
    top = top + 20;        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this small exmple of how it can be accomplished. I have not written the complete code..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vjU5b/32/)